# Difference between terms and clauses in a contract

Tags: contract-law, legal-terms

I'm new to legal terminology used in contracts. I'm trying to understand the difference between terms of a contract and clauses of a contract. All the sites have referred so far provide no clear distinction between the two and sometimes use terms and clauses interchangeably. I'm wondering if there is any difference between the two or not.

I found a similar question asked before: [What's the difference between a clause, provision, condition and term?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/6324/whats-the-difference-between-a-clause-provision-condition-and-term) but it doesn't answers the question in the context of purchase or legal contracts.

Also, from a conceptual point of view, does a contract contain anything other than terms, name of the signing parties and clauses?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Terms and clauses are the apples and oranges of a contract.

First of all —

> from a conceptual point of view, does a contract contain anything other than terms, name of the signing parties and clauses?

— most contracts do not even need to be in writing (and thus do not need to contain any "signing parties" or "clauses"). What makes up a contract is a separate question but, again, a writing is only necessary for certain types of contracts (e.g. real estate contracts).

**Terms** of a contract exist regardless of whether it is in writing or not: they are plainly specific *information* (or *knowledge*) about the contract that the parties have agreed on: who the parties are, what they do for each other and what they get in return, times, places, numbers and whatever the parties consider essential to the contract. This information/knowledge may just stay in the minds of the parties and never be rendered in a readable form. The contract will be perfectly valid and enforceable.

**Clauses** are what written contracts composed of. They are just blocks of text each addressing specific aspect or concern of the contract e.g. Parties, Payment, Delivery, Force majeure, Termination, Jurisdiction etc.

Comment: Thank you! For written contracts, what is the relationship between Terms and Clauses? Does a clause contain a term? Also, I have seen the phrase payment terms and pricing terms being used a lot, is there any difference between payment clause and payment terms?

Comment: @user401445 Payment clause refers to a certain chunk of the contract text (e.g. a paragraph). This chunk will detail payment terms i.e. information on how/when/how much one party pays to the other. Written contracts will often contain all payment terms within the payment clause, but terms may also be spread across several clauses (not necessarily payment-focused) or further detailed in schedules. Payment terms can also be paraphrased and communicated using different words than written in the payment clause — they will remain the same terms. Clauses can only be communicated literally.

Comment: I'd add that while a "term" (well defined in this answer) is a pretty well defined semantic unit, the term "clause" has a less consistent meaning. A clause can refer to a block of text as small as part of a sentence, but is a word sometimes instead uses to refer to a sentence, a paragraph, a section, or even a full mini-contractual addendum to a contract. The term "clause" is never used to refer to the entire contract, however, and is more often used to refer to text modifying or qualifying another part of the text, but can also be used generically as synonymous with a numbered section.

Comment: Thank you @Greendrake @ohwilleke! Based on what you mentioned, is it fair to say that terms always exist within a clause while clauses are standalone and there could be clauses without terms?

Comment: @user401445 Clauses are meant to contain/express terms at all times. Clauses without terms would make no sense but this doesn't mean they can't exist.

Comment: @user401445 An example of clause without a term would typically be a bunch of archaic preamble language at the beginning of a contract, and more pertinently, causes which contain various statements regarding the status quo situation or representations of the parties. A clause of the contract might say, for example, "The subject property is located in the County of Arapahoe, in the State of Colorado.", which is a statement of fact, rather than a "term" of the contract, i.e. part of the promise created by the contract.

Comment: @user401445 A clause could also contain a required legal notice that is not a term. For example, real estate contracts in Colorado drafted by realtors without lawyers are required to contain text stating something along the lines of: "This property may be located in a special taxing district and if it does you are obligated to pay taxes to it." or "WARNING: It is possible for oil and gas rights and water rights to be severed from surface property ownership rights in Colorado." or "This is an important legal document and you should consider consulting legal and/or tax counsel before signing."

Comment: @user401445 "terms always exist within a clause" No. Important terms of a contract are implied in law whether or not expressly stated in a contract. For example, in a contract for the sale of goods from a merchant, there is an implied warranty of merchantability (i.e. non-defectiveness) and a warranty of title (i.e. authority to sell the good since you own it or can deliver title to it without owing it) unless it is expressly disclaimed (e.g. in an "as is" sale of used goods, or a "quitclaim deed" type transfer of goods in litigation).

Comment: @user401445 Despite all of this it is not uncommon at all for the word "term" to be used to refer to a bit of text better called a "term". There is actually a term in English grammar/linguistics referring the the subset of figurative language that refers to an intangible concept by its tangible embodiment, and another one for the reverse, but neither of them come to me off the cuff.

Comment: @ohwilleke Thanks for the detailed explanation, it was super helpful.